# Difference between this.member and this::member in java and kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

What is the main difference in accessing a member reference in kotlin and java

Comment: I don't remember Java, but for kotlin, `this.member` ~ getting `member` value. `this::member` is the reference of the getter method. For example, if you have a method that requires a lambda for getting `member` value inside, you can pass `foo(this::member)`.

Comment: "in kotlin and java"—That is two different questions.

Comment: @Tuan Chau  explained correctly. It is the same concept **valid for Java** as well. `this.member` is accessing member of current class and for :: refer [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-colon-operator-in-java/).

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

`this.member` accesses the value of a property/variable when it is executed while `this::member` gets a reference to the property that can be used later in order to access the property. Property/variable references do not work in Java.

### Kotlin

##### `this::member`

See [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#property-references).

`this::member` gets a **property object** of the property `member`. You can use it to get (and set if it is mutable) the value of the member **at any point**.

If you use `this::member`, change the value of the member variable and use the reference obtained earlier with `this::member`, you will get the **new value** and you can also **change the value of the original member** using the member reference after you obtained it.

##### `this.member`

`this.member` allows to get (and set if it is mutable) the value of the property **at the moment you access `this.member`**.

If you use `this.member`, change the value of the member varianle and use the value obtained earlier with `this::member`, you will get the **old value** and while you can change the obtained value, this will **not reflect on the original value**.

##### Example

This example illustrates the difference between `this.member` and `this::member`:

```kotlin
class TestClass {
    var member="default value"
    fun showDifference() {
        val obj=TestClass()
        val ref=obj::member
        var value=obj.member
        println(ref.get())//default value
        println(value)//default value
        ref.set("changed by ref")
        println(obj.member)//changed by ref
        println(ref.get())//changed by ref
        println(value)//default value
        obj.member="changed directly"
        println(ref.get())//changed directly
        println(value)//default value
        value="changed by value"
        println(ref.get())//changed directly
        println(value)//changed by value
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    TestClass().showDifference()
}
```

### Java

##### `this::member`

In Java, `this::member` does not work (compiler error), you can only access method references of methods and not variables.

However, you can get a method reference of a getter/setter method and call that method at a later point.

##### `this.member`

`this.member` just accesses the member variable when it is executed.